# Img tag is not displaying the image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It's my first time to have this kind of problem. As you can see on the IMG tag, the image is not visible. I'm not sure what can cause this problem. When I copy the link and insert it in a new tab, the image is there. I tried to add a new class and define width/height but didn't fix the problem

```
    @foreach (var theimg in Model.AdExtraImages)
    {
        <img src="~/adimages/@theimg.AdId/@theimg.Image" class="the-extra-image"/>
    }
```

[image]

URL(copy/paste new tab, where the image is ok):
https://localhost:44374/ads/4/adimages/1015/0f25eed4-1413-4854-96a7-6cdfb2300d9e_esresr.jpg

**Problem solved** I disabled adblocker

Comment: what's the CSS doing for that img? Just based on the HTML part of the screenshot, it looks like it's being hidden

Comment: CSS: width:120px; height:120px; object-fit:cover; . I added CSS in case it will fix the problem. When I hover on the src, it says "Could not load the image". Its weird, because when I copy/paste the same link in other tab, it seems ok

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see your image with enable adblocker,
Rename your ads and adimages to other names that do not include ads, advertisements, etc.